# How to print an updating loading bar on console?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-interface, loading

I was hoping someone would know how to code for a percentage number, but so that it is on the same line (breaking line continuation).

I have this code:

```
Changenumber = int(0)
while Changenumber<100:

    Changenumber += 1
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print(Changenumber)
    print("%")
```

The problem is that this displays the percentages line after line like this:

```
1%
2%
3%
4%
5%
etc.
```

For an example on the same line code, this puts loading... on the same line:

```
import time
for x in range (0,4):
    b = "Loading" + "." * x
    print (b, end="\r")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please don't post unindented Python code. Indentation is required for Python code to make sense.

Comment: So you already know about `end="\r"`. What specific difficulty did you have about applying it to the percentage case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following example:

```
import time
for x in range (4):
    # Carriage return to the beginning of the line and then writing the percentages loaded message
    print(f'\r{x}%', end='')
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot! New to python coding. Glad for your help.

Comment: Welcome @DareD3vil! Please mark as solved and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'tqdm' library.

```
from tqdm import tqdm 
import time  
  
for i in tqdm (range (101),desc="Loading…",ascii=False,ncols=75): 
    time.sleep(0.02) 
      
print("Complete.")
```